# Iframe src different to parent domain not loading in Safari MAC and iOS devices

Tags: javascript, macos, iframe, safari, cross-domain

I am having issues with the following.

We have an iframe with src="foo.com" that sits on page bar.foo.com, it works in every browser barring safari for Mac and iOS devices.

I've tried setting the document.domain to match, but this doesn't work.

When inspecting the element the html and body tags get rendered but the  is empty.

HELP?!

Answer (score -2):

It should work unless the URL you are trying to iframe has a deny policy for iframes using the following header:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

If no such header exist, then you should be able to load the content but not modify such content because of the Same-Origin policy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Comment: It is not a reason for iframe to break

Comment: @BogdanBurim Care to elaborate, the statement you posted is too vague for me to understand. Are you saying that SOP restriction is not causing the iframe content to show?

Comment: @BogdanBurim I guess we have to agree to disagree. Unless you have something to back your theory up, I will stick to facts when it comes to SOP (which I personally have worked with plenty of times).

Comment: You are saying that it is impossible to load Iframe which has src with url to different domain from current. I say that you are wrong very much. For example youtube video used to be embed via iframe. http://fuzzyraygun.com/youtube-iframe-embeds-not-working-on-ios-devices-fix/  What will you say here? Same Origin Policy is not what you think. It does not limit iframe URl.

Comment: @BogdanBurim You are correct. I was thinking of the frame options deny and not the SOP but was indeed a mistake on my part. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Even after setting these options in web config of the site which is trying to load url from another.domain.com , it does not work in safari 12. I see that ALLOW-FROM is not compatible with Safari 12 anyway. Is there any code fix ?     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://another.domain.com/" />
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM https://another.domain.com/" />